# Jquery - Animate - Bootstrap Modal window

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use below code for the bootstrap modal window. But, it's not responding. I understand the modal window was position fixed and top of the layout. I want to move my modal window screen to move top.

Manual scroll top & bottom works fine.

```
$('html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
```

Does any solution exist to move the Bootstrap modal window scroll position?

Thanks

Comment: Using the above code your webpage will scroll to top. I don't see anything that will move the `Modal` to the top of the screen in your code

Comment: @Shuvo Yes, my web page scrolls fine. Not modal window. Thats why not sure how to move my modal window to scroll top